# Программа завершается нулевым кодом вместо вывода строки

Tags: c#

````
        ```var str = "Дана строка. Вывести подстроку, расположенную между первой и второй1|последней2 точками исходной строки. Если в строке менее двух точек, то вывести всю исходную строку.";
        var result = str.IndexOf('.') == str.LastIndexOf('.') ? str : str.Substring(str.IndexOf('.') + 1, str.LastIndexOf('.') - str.IndexOf('.'));
        Console.WriteLine(result);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не успеваете увидеть результат. Добавьте в конце Вашего кода:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```